# bind strange behavior with ping

Tags: bind, ping

I've BIND on my lan and I created a zone:

```
$ORIGIN example.com.
$TTL 604800 ; 1 week
@       IN SOA  ns1.example.com. max.example.com. (
                2017103151 ; serial
                604800     ; refresh (1 week)
                86400      ; retry (1 day)
                2419200    ; expire (4 weeks)
                604800     ; minimum (1 week)
                )
        IN  NS  ns1.example.com.
        IN  NS  ns2.example.com.
            MX  10 mx1.example.com.

server1         A   192.168.1.100
ns1         A   192.168.1.101
ns2         A   192.168.1.102
mx1         A   192.168.1.100
ftp         CNAME   server1
pop3            CNAME   server1
imap            CNAME   server1
```

REVERSE ZONE:

```
$ORIGIN 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
$TTL 604800     ; 1 week
@       IN SOA  ns1.example.com. max.example.com. (
                                2017103136 ; serial
                                604800     ; refresh (1 week)
                                86400      ; retry (1 day)
                                2419200    ; expire (4 weeks)
                                604800     ; minimum (1 week)
                                )
                IN      NS      ns1.example.com.
                IN      NS      ns2.example.com.
100                     PTR     ftp.example.com.
100                     PTR     mx1.example.com.
100                     PTR     www.example.com.
100                     PTR     smtp.example.com.
100                     PTR     mail.example.com.
100                     PTR     pop3.example.com.
100                     PTR     imap.example.com.
101                     PTR     ns1.example.com.
102                     PTR     ns2.example.com.
```

Everything works, but there's a strange behavior with ping command:

```
ping mx1.example.com
64 bytes from www.example.com (192.168.1.100): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.102 ms

ping imap.example.com
64 bytes from pop3.example.com (192.168.1.100): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.102 ms
```

Comment: You seem to get round-robin results for *reverse lookups*. If you have a reverse zone (1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.) , check that for multiple entries or check your hosts file for multiple entries. The forward zone looks correct BTW

Comment: Also https://serverfault.com/questions/618700/why-multiple-ptr-records-in-dns-is-not-recommended

Comment: dear god why RR rDNS

Answer (score 1):

This is a normal behavior and you get similar results when trying to ping `www.google.com`. Here is an example:

```
khaled@my-server:~$ ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (216.58.212.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lhr35s06-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.212.100): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=94.5 ms
64 bytes from lhr35s06-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.212.100): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=96.0 ms
64 bytes from lhr35s06-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.212.100): icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=94.5 ms
```

You can see the returned name is different than original name used in ping command. This is clearly a reverse DNS name. To verify, you can use the following command:

```
khaled@my-server:~$ host 216.58.212.100
100.212.58.216.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer lhr35s06-in-f100.1e100.net.
100.212.58.216.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer lhr35s06-in-f4.1e100.net.
```

You can disable reverse lookup using `-n` option like:

```
khaled@my-server:~$ ping -n www.google.com
PING www.google.com (216.58.212.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 216.58.212.100: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=94.6 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.212.100: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=94.6 ms
```