# Is it possible to make reverse dns lookup on cloudflare

Tags: reverse-dns, cloudflare

Somehow Cloudflare is hiding the real ip of my server. Is there a possibility to check other domains on my ip by reverse DNS?

in short I make

```
dig some-server-name.com
```

I got in reply some A records...but they are not actually my server ip's

than I make `dig -x ip.I.got.earlier`
and in resulr I got:

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
67.172.in-addr.arpa.    600 IN  SOA cruz.ns.cloudflare.com. dns.cloudflare.com. 2034580120 10000 2400 604800 3600
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are looking up the IP for a cloudflare server, not your own server.  You need to use your own server IP.   This is called your Origin and Origin IP.

Once you know your own server IP then you can try to figure out what is on that. I guess this must be shared hosting if it is your server or.... are you really trying to figure out the IP for someone else's server?   Your own server IP should be available in your DNS or through your Cloudflare control panel.

If this is your own server, you should be happy that your IP is obscured.  That is how this is designed to work.  Just log into your cloudflare account and check your settings for your real IP!

Comment: thx. it all I need.

Answer (score 0):

DNS reverse lookup fetches the PTR record related to the IP address. In theory, there could be multiple PTR records per IP address, but in practice there is only one domain name record.

This means that one cannot see all the domain names that point to a single IP address.

[Why multiple PTR records in DNS is not recommended](https://serverfault.com/questions/618700/why-multiple-ptr-records-in-dns-is-not-recommended) provides more information on the PTR records and why only one PTR record / IP address is used.